# Snowboard Boots with the Throwback?

Tags: gear, footwear, snowboarding

I've just got a new [Burton Throwback](http://www.burton.com/default/throwback-snowboard/W16-159771.html), and was wondering how you use it. The instinctive choice seems to be to wear snowboard boots with it. However, there are no ski lifts in my test field  so to prevent excruciating pain when walking up and down the hill, would wearing normal walking boots work?

Just an extra question, do I need to wax the base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a backyard board like that back in the early 90s, you can wear whatever boots you want with that board. Snowboard boots were developed for supportive snowboard bindings, those old boards didn't have supportive bindings, just toe straps like what you found on water skis and surf boards.

[image]

You don't *need* to wax the bases, but you will glide faster if you do, but I'd probably just use a glide wax, I'm not sure how well hot wax would stick.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a lot of puff where you plan to use it, consider a pair of snowshoes (which you can totally use with snowboard boots, just make sure the snowshoe straps are long enough). Most backcountry backpacks will have straps to attach the board on the way up, and the snowshoes on the way down.

Otherwise aim for the least stiff snowboard boots, as they will be more comfortable to walk. Consider models with fast fastening systems (boas, for example).

I would not recommend walking boots at all. Those won't protect you from the cold, the straps from the board will be uncomfortable, and snowboard boots are higher, which provides better control (I find).

Comment: Well they're winter walking boots (Scarpa SL Active) would they work?

Comment: those look like heavy boots, but I wouldn't call that winter boot. For one, I couldn't find any mention of what type of insulation they use or what is their temperature rating.

Comment: I don't know, sorry :P

Comment: Have you actually walked in powdery snow with those shoes? If so, there is nothing wrong in trying to strap the board on your feet to see how it works.

Comment: However, I doubt the benefits would be so great. I use snowshoes with snowboard shoes, and I find it to be the easiest way to go up (apart from lifts, obviously), and I find that snowshoeing with snowboard shoes is just as easy as with walking boots. (I don't see myself walking up knee-deep (or worst) for hours with bare shoes instead of using snowshoes)